# Message queue bad file descriptor error

Tags: c++, posix, message-queue

I write a simple application to understand POSIX message queues. But the app continuously gives "Bad file descriptor" error.

Thanks to stackoverflow users. We find the solution. Below is the updated code.

```
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <errno.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    mqd_t messageQueue;
    mq_attr attr;
    messageQueue = mq_open("/test",O_RDWR|O_CREAT,0664,&attr);

    attr.mq_maxmgs = 10;
    attr.mq_msgsize = 4;

    char c;
    int pid = fork();
    //client
    if(pid == 0) {
        if(mq_receive(messageQueue,&c,1,0) == -1)
            cout<<"Error:"<<strerror(errno)<<"\n";
        cout<<"Received:"<<c<<"\n";
    }
    //server
    else if(pid > 0) {
        c = 'a';
        if(mq_send(messageQueue,&c,1,0) == -1)
            cout<<"Error:"<<strerror(errno)<<"\n";
        cout<<"Send:"<<c<<"\n";
        mq_close(messageQueue);
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Fork error\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about checking the return value of `mq_open` to know if it worked or not?

Comment: @Mat I just tried. It is not working. It says "Invalid argument"

Comment: Well that's your problem. Read the man page, look at what it says about `EINVAL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you provide `O_CREAT` flag  and an attribute list to `mq_open`, you should explicitly set `attr.mq_maxmsg` and `attr.mq_msgsize` to a positive value.

Comment: @unknown_user you are absolutely right and one more thing according to man page for mq_overview message queue name should start with a slash(/)

Answer (score 0):

error exist because the receiving buffer size is not greater than mq_msgsize attribute.
just do two things make an array say char c1[50] and a pointer to it say char *ptr=c1;
pass this pointer in receive method and when u print message print c1[0] that's it.
Also update the size in receive method to 50 and not 1.